# Most efficient way of Saving Twitter Feeds

Tags: android, twitter

So this is how my app is supposed to work.

1. User subscribes to a new feed on twitter.
2. That particular feed is displayed on a different page. (Works till here)
3. That page is to be retained until the next time the app is opened and when refreshed gives the latest feeds. (When I go back to the main menu and try to view that particular feed, it hangs).

Right now I have tried to implement it by using Shared Preferences but I'm not sure if this is the right way to do it. Is this a correct approach? Is there any other way of doing this? I'm pretty new to this so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should be using a sqlite database not shared prefs.

Comment: [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html) a very good tutorial about it

Comment: If you are already parsing the feeds into java objects this should be pretty easy to implement. What is your minimum android version?

Comment: I'm running it on 4.2.2. And yes this is what I used to display:
tweetDisplay.setText(tweetResultBuilder.toString());
And also, I only display the User Name and the Tweet.

Comment: I would recommend using the database with a CursorLoader... I have posted a few links as an answer to get you started but if you have any trouble let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some good reading...

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

But I recommend using a CursorLoader...

http://developer.android.com/training/load-data-background/index.html

Comment: The CursorLoader looks a little less daunting than SQlite. Thank you.

Comment: It is still sqlite but the CursorLoader handles a lot of the work for you.

Comment: Just to update, because I had only two fields of data to load for a limited number of feeds, I found it way easier (and possibly more effective) to use internal storage files. Store and then display. It works perfectly so far.

Comment: That is a workable way but not something I would recommend. You may run into issues with partially downloaded files and random parsing errors. Do as you please but I highly recommend taking the extra time to learn how to use the CursorLoader and a sqlite database.